# Can an ant etch a hole in a tent with formic acid?

Tags: acid-base

Given a polymer foil tent, could ant's formic acid help to etch a hole in it? I thought of a polyester or polyamid foil. If one ant's acid is not enough, they come as team.

This is not a theoretical question beacause I have observed it on a camping in South France. I am not just sure whether they just bite through, or indeed use their acid.

https://ibb.co/m5u5B8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would be VERY surprised if it did. The answer depends on what material the tent is made of. Most tents now days are made of polyester and according to the table below (taken from: http://rfelektronik.se/manuals/Datasheets/solventguide.pdf) polyester has good resistance in formic acid (Note, S stands for satisfactory in table).

However, even if it was nylon, unsatisfactory resistance means that the material will deteriorate in hours to weeks when used with the chemical. I dont think an ant or some ants would be able to produce enough acid to seriously damage the thick fibers of the tent. Maybe if a lot of ants were attacking the same spot one after the other you would eventually dissolve some of the nylon to make a small hole, you never know.

Also, an ant attacking a tent is a very unlikely scenario (ants use formic acid to defend themselves).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer; actually, they really did it! https://ibb.co/m5u5B8 may be just biting through, if you say the acid is rather not relevant.

Comment: @J.Doe So, assuming the hole was not already there and the ants just found a way in it, i wouldnt be surprised at all if they chew through. That is their job after all! For example carpenter ants chew through wood and also see here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ants/comments/8flc4y/can_ants_eat_through_plastic/